# Is there a php.ini directive that enables stack traces on errors?

Tags: php

Is there a php.ini directive that enables stack traces on errors?  I already looked here: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php.  My shared-hosting does not have Xdebug installed for some reason.  I tried putting these in .htaccess:

```
php_value track_erors On
php_value report_zend_debug 1
```

but no stack trace.

Comment: "My shared-hosting does not have Xdebug installed for some reason" - Probably because their service is designed to host apps. Development should be done in your local PC. There's no need to slow down live sites with debugging extensions.

Answer (score 7):

There's [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace). This won't work for fatal errors though, since those cannot be handled.

Example:

```
<?php
function exceptions_error_handler($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) { 
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

set_error_handler('exceptions_error_handler');

function c() {
echo $a;
}

c();
```

gives:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'file' => string '/tmp/cpu7HL5A' (length=13)
      'line' => int 9
      'function' => string 'exceptions_error_handler' (length=24)
      'args' => 
        array
          0 => &int 8
          1 => &string 'Undefined variable: a' (length=21)
          2 => &string '/tmp/cpu7HL5A' (length=13)
          3 => &int 9
          4 => &
            array
              empty
  1 => 
    array
      'file' => string '/tmp/cpu7HL5A' (length=13)
      'line' => int 12
      'function' => string 'c' (length=1)
      'args' => 
        array
          empty
```

Answer (score 1):

not directly but you can call `debug_backtrace()` OR catch your errors and have the exception class dump its stack trace with `exception::getTrace();`

Comment: Fine, but this applies to exceptions, not errors. Errors can be caught with set_error_handler, but that doesn't provide a stack trace.