# PHP - Enable a stack trace on errors

Tags: php, ubuntu, stack, trace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a php.ini directive that enables stack traces on errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224809/is-there-a-php-ini-directive-that-enables-stack-traces-on-errors)

I am setting up a LAMP sever on Ubuntu and want to enable the error stack trace. I had this on a server that I used before where it would out put a stack of the functions that it was running when the error occurred. This was very helpful when debugging. I didn't set up the server I saw this on so I have no idea what was enabled or installed. Is there something I need to do to the .ini file or do I need to install something. If it is an install if you could provide the Aptitude command to install it that would be fantastic.

Comment: Might be a dupe: look at the second answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224809/is-there-a-php-ini-directive-that-enables-stack-traces-on-errors

Answer (score 2):

Try XDebug.

http://xdebug.org/

You can then have all sorts of new debugging features enabled, including stack tracing.

It's also easy to install via pecl:

http://xdebug.org/docs/install